# Do I need to invite Sylvain to complete Share a Bite?

Tags: fire-emblem-three-houses

On my first day as a professor, Sylvain gave me the quest *Share a Bite*. The quest details imply I need to eat with Sylvain:

> The food in the dining hall’s pretty appetizing. Is anyone interested in sharing a meal? Ladies preferred.

I'd rather invite someone else for my first meal. Do I need to eat with Sylvain to complete *Share a Bite*, or can I invite someone else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to invite Sylvain to complete *Share a Bite*. In fact, there wasn't even an option to invite Sylvain when I went to the dining hall. The Quest Completion dialogue seems to imply you *can't* invite Sylvain to your first meal.

> Heh, so you're getting right to it! I'm impressed to find someone who's more proactive than I am. Nice going, Professor. All right, then. **Next time will be my turn!**